# .NET application with an Oracle Database

Tags: .net, asp.net, oracle10g

I have to code a desktop application and some dynamic web content.
I'm planning to develop it in **.NET** with an **Oracle database**, though my dilemma is that my professor says that if I do so, there would be a lot of support issues later on.
He says .NET is more compatible with MS SQL and MS Access, and so is the trend, everyone does it.Is it true?

I have learnt Oracle so I know of a few features which I wouldn't be able to implement on SQL comfortably because of lack of knowledge of SQL databases.I would love to learn the new syntax but again, I don't have much time to spare.

Comment: As Oded said: People use Oracle with .NET in production systems all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.NET uses a [provider model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model) for database access.

It is not more or less compatible with any specific database.

You can use either the ADODB provider that is a generic one that should work with all databases that support ODBC, or use an Oracle specific one.

Using an Oracle specific provider should give you access to Oracle specific features.

People use Oracle with .NET in production systems all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) which is Oracle's library for accessing Oracle databases from the .net world.

It's getting richer and richer, I think the latest beta even has support for entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Lets not forget that SQL is meant to be a standard rather than a particular company's implementation. That said the reality is far different from it being standard across platforms.

You should not be swayed into thinking that you have to use the MS stack all the way just because it is common. You can use ODBC to connect to almost any database and so abstract your application from the underlying infrastructure.

Choose the tools you are most productive with if they can do the job well.

Comment: You are right, let's mention that anyway ODBC is not the only way to abstract upper layers from the database product down in the information layer. It depends more on the pattern you use, with a factory one you could abstract as well.

Answer (score 0):

ODP.Net is specifically design to integrate Oracle database with .NET application. You wont face any issues with is. Am already working on this for past 4 year. This works same as native SQL client with no issues.